# Inference in virtuoso 7.x

Tags: ontology, semantic-web, virtuoso, inference, reasoning

I am reading that virtuoso 7.x does not support SWRL but is there an alternative way to achieve (in Virtuoso 7.x) the following:
Given:

```
<a> <relationship_1> <b>. 
<b> <relationship_2> <c>.
```

Infer:

```
<a> <relationship_3> <c>.
```

Any sort of suggestion would be appreciated.

P.S: One way is to materialize these `<a> <relationship_3> <c> .` but am not interested in doing that.

Thanks

Comment: At a minimum, you'll also need some statements that describe the relationships between `<relationship_1>`, `<relationship_2>`, and `<relationship_3>`, as nothing can make the inference you describe here from the 2 statements you've "given". Perhaps this article will get you started -- <https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/using-british-royal-family-data-snippets-to-demonstrate-sparql-query-language-based-reasoning-56626a152419>. If not, <https://community.openlinksw.com/> is better for Virtuoso-specific questions than this general programming site.

Comment: Thanks @TallTed, I did go through these blogs and I do understand that if we have relationship among these `<relationship_1>`, `<relationship_2>`, and `<relationship_3>`, we could use rdfs / owl semantics to infer things. Also, when you say `nothing can make the  inference with these two statements`, you mean in the absence of SWRL or any other SPARQL based rules, right?

Comment: I mean that given *only* the 2 statements "given" above (which is all you "gave"), nothing can infer the third. "SWRL or any other SPARQL based rules" including RDFS/OWL semantics would be more than those 2 statements.